# "To be an influence" or "to have an influence"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Is there a rule for when one has to say *to be a positive influence on...* or *to have a positive influence on...*? For example,

> The practice of singing songs **is/has** a positive influence on people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example sentence, using '*is*' sounds very awkward to me. '*Has*' seems much more natural.

I'm not sure if there's a rule, but in general, I'd recommend using '*is/was*' when talking about people, for example:

> His father was a positive influence on him.

And '*has/had*' when talking about things or concepts:

> The presence of his father had a positive influence in his life.

Answer (score 0):

One should be a good influence on others.

He had a good infuence on his peers.

In my opinion both are grammatically correct.

Comment: "In my opinion" is a bad start to an answer. Opinion-based answers aren't considered good quality. I'm not saying you're wrong. But include links to definitions/sources backing up your claim.